# Help needed designing a 'Group' concept for students in a class

Tags: database-design, normalization

I've been wracking my brain for a while now trying to figure out how to fit this part of my domain model into the database, but whatever I come up with just feels wrong.

I've attached a picture below of my current schema (it still needs a bit of work, but I'm focused only on this one issue right now).

The idea I need to model is as follows:

- One or more students can potentially team up to form a group for the purposes of completing and submitting homework assignments.
- A "group" is only valid for a given assignment. For subsequent assignments, a new group would need to be constructed. It may still consist of the same people as before, but this new group will receive a new identifier in the system.
- Grades will be assigned to groups as a whole, so every student in the group will be getting the same grade.

One of my original ideas was to have a "Groups" table that would hold some metadata about the group, but there's no metadata that I can think of that would be meaningful, other than knowing what students are in the group, and for what assignment they are forming the group. This ultimately led me to having a join table with "User ID" and "Assignment ID" as foreign keys, while "Group ID" is a value that allows me to indicate that anywhere between 1 and n rows are in the same group. This column would necessarily be not unique, and therefore cannot form a primary key.

Is there a better solution for this than what I managed to come up with? Everything about this current design feels wrong, and I can't quite figure out why.

[image]